# Cannot Upvote Question in iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Due to confusion in the way I previously worded this question, I am rewriting it for clarity and possible steps to reproduce

- Received a push notification of a comment on my answer
- Swiped to read comment, (launching app)
- Switched tab from **Answers** to **Question**
- Tried to upvote the question
- Received error:

  > You can't vote for your own post

Again, I tried to upvote a *question* to which I'd posted an *answer* but I did not ask the *question*.

This failed in the iOS app, but did work on the website.

Link to question:
[Continue to read in file after if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21691176/3130539)

---

Edit: reproducable, now with screenshot:

> [image]

You can just barely make out at the bottom of frame that the user I'm trying to vote on is *not* me! But I did get to this page via my answer.

Comment: provide us with the question you were trying to answer

Comment: @PrototypeStark edited question with link

Comment: @mhlester did you downvote the question before trying to upvote?

Comment: @Raghunandan, nope. I only tried to upvote, and only on the app. I just tried in browser and it worked. Definitely a problem exclusive to the app

Comment: @mhlester if you feel its a bug or a you need to request a feature ask a question on metag with android-app tag.

Comment: @mhlester I have seen this error previously, and this usecase should help me track it down... I'll post any updates once I find a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that, coming from the inbox, we only had an answer identifier available, without the corresponding question identifier . This was causing the voting logic to wrongly assume we need to upvote/downvote the answer instead of the question. That's why you were getting that error – the app was **actually trying to upvote your own answer**!

This has been fixed and will be available in tonight's build.